# Triggering Power Automate after 14 days from the date when a specific list field is updated in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, power-automate

I have a requirement to trigger a power automate workflow after 14 days from when a specific field gets updated in a SharePoint list.

Please guide me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look into the following options below:

A) Trigger - **[When an item is created or modified]**

1. Set a **trigger condition** so that Power Automate is triggered only when the **[Specified]** field has a specific value like `@equals(triggerBody()?['SpecifiedField']?['Value'], 'Pending')`
2. Within the body of the Power Automate, wrap business logic by adding a **[Delay]** action and set it to delay for 14 days.
3. Power Automate will starts in this case, but business logic will be not be processed until after 14 days has passed.

B) Use **Scheduled/Recurrence** Power Automate

1. SharePoint List Update

   Add a *calculated* column, say [ChangedDate], with expression like `=IF(Title="ABC",TODAY(),DATE(2050,12,20))` . In the example, [Title] is the specified field. When updated to a specified value, capture and store the current date and time. Also, add another column of type *Choice*, named it like [FlowStatus] with default being **Pending** that gets updated to **Completed** from Power Automate once it completes.
2. In Power Automate - schedule to run daily

   Using [Get items] action with a filter like `Title eq 'ABC' and FlowStatus eq 'Pending'`, retrieve all items from the list
3. Add a [Filter] action to further filter out items that were updated **14** days earlier. Since [Get items] **does not** allow filtering on a **Calculated** column, this additional filter is required.
   Here is an example of the Filter expressions: `[ChangedDate] is less than addDays(utcNow(), -14, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK')`.
4. Add [Apply to each] to process each item in the filtered out items list
5. Within, [Apply to each], update each items [FlowStatus] to **Completed**

Comment: If you are working with a "large" list, be mindful of the limitations and boundaries of Flow/Power Automate.  Last year I tried something like this and Microsoft throttled the Flow and canceled all pending Flows.  The root issue was related to having too many Flows pending/waiting/running at one time.

Comment: Updated my response with another option. I think, option B would work better.